# MySQL date search

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a query that compares yyyy-mm-dd to yyyy-mm

I am only interested in seeing if there is an existing entry for a specific yyyy-mm but the dates are store in the tables as yyyy-mm-dd

I have tried some variations of `DATE_FORMAT(pledge_date, '%Y%m')='$MMYY'`

can anyone help?

Comment: ok I feel dumb as soon as i posted i came up with the answer  DATE_FORMAT(pledge_date, '%Y%m') = DATE_FORMAT(now(), '%Y%m')

Answer (score 1):

severalpossibilities...

```
WHERE DATE(pledge_date) = CURDATE()

WHERE DATE(pledge_date) = DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(unix-timstamp))

WHERE DATE(pledge_date) = '2012-02-28'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DATE_FORMAT(`date_column`,'%Y%m') = 'YYYYMM'
```

where 'YYYYMM' is '201203' or whatever month you're looking for

Answer (score 1):

There's also [`EXTRACT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_extract):

```
EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM pledge_date) = YYYYMM
```

And [`SUBSTR`/`SUBSTRING`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substr):

```
SUBSTR(pledge_date,1,7) = 'YYYY-MM'
```

Answer (score 0):

I've done this a few times, & like to use MySQL's `MONTH()` and `YEAR()` functions in a query. For example:

```
SELECT * FROM `my_table` WHERE MONTH(datefield)='06' AND YEAR(datefield)='2013'
```

That should select all rows in `my_table`, where the the datefield field is 2013-06.